# Free solvers or techniques to solve nonlinear programming problems with linear OBJ and nonlinear constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve a nonlinear programming problem (no integer). The objective function is linear and some constraints are nonlinear (bilinear). The performance of conopt solver is not good enough. So I am looking for other solvers (free) to solve or some techniques to treat the problem. Can anyone give me some ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Conopt uses an active set method (SQP). It may make sense to try a solver that uses a different algorithm such as Ipopt (interior point). The latest version of Gurobi also supports non-convex quadratic constraints, so that may be another thing to try out.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks Erwin. I use GAMS to code and solve the problem. The programming is straightforward according to the physical meaning. Ipopt definitely deserve a try. I am also thinking about other mathematical techniques, like dual and decomposition etc., to solve the problem. But I am new to these areas. Hopefully, I can get some suggestions from here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple nonlinear programming problem solved with IPOPT, as suggested by @ErwinKalvelagen - there are several packages for nonlinear programming optimization, such as `pyomo`, `gekko`, and others. There is a nice discussion on [High Quality Nonlinear Programming Solvers in Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python). Below are a few examples in `gekko` that I maintain:

**Nonlinear Programming**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = x
# change initial values
x2.value = 5; x3.value = 5
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

With integer variables, switch to the APOPT solver (MINLP) with `m.options.SOLVER=1`.

**Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = [# maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5)
# Integer constraints for x3 and x4
x3 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
x4 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
# Equations
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3) # Objective
m.solve(disp=False) # Solve
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

**Mixed Integer Linear Programming**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x,y = m.Array(m.Var,2,integer=True,lb=0) 
m.Maximize(y)
m.Equations([-x+y<=1,
             3*x+2*y<=12,
             2*x+3*y<=12])
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
print('Objective: ', -m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
print('x: ', x.value[0])
print('y: ', y.value[0])
```